# Почему не работает haproxy?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, amazon

На amazon.com создал два инстанца с ubuntu. На обоих пробовал настраивать haproxy. На одном инстансе haproxy работает, апитаблес на нем не трогал. На другом после неудачной настройки iptables перестал работать curl localhost, выдает 503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request. Пробовал ребутить инстанс, не помогает. Помогите разобраться в чем может быть дело.

Вот что делал с апитэйблс:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i $WAN -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s ... -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Haproxy config:

```
    global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        contimeout 5000
        clitimeout 50000
        srvtimeout 50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend tutorial_im
        bind *:80
        default_backend tutorial_http
backend tutorial_http
        balance roundrobin
        mode http
        server web1 *.*.*.*:80 check
```

вывод iptables -L -nv:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2749 packets, 232K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5704 packets, 675K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел причину, дело было ни в iptables ни в линуксе. В Amazone EC2 есть свой фаервол который блокирует все соединения по-умолчанию.